# How to assign FileReader base64 into a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, es6-promise

I tried to print the base46 data and it is coming by:

```
var fileData;
var files = document.getElementById('pickUpFileAttachment').files;
if (files.length > 0) {

    var promise = getBase64(files[0]);
    promise.then(function (result) {

        fileData = result;
        console.log(result);
    });

}

function getBase64(file, onLoadCallback) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            resolve(reader.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
```

In `console.log(result)` the data is present but when i assign it to `fileData` and try to console it after the end of `getBase64()` function i get `undefined`. How can i assign the base64 data to a variable?

```
console.log("displaying the 64base data");
console.log(fileData);
```

It just showed me `undefined` of `fileData` value.
[image]

Comment: I don't think you understand asynchronous programming model, you haven't calculated the base64 right after the function definition, otherwise what would be the point of using promises? Also if `pickUpFileAttachment` is a file input you should be listening to an onChange event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise is asynchronous and it seems you want to retrieve `fileData` synchronously. In this case when your `fileData` executed but your promise does not resolve cause it asynchronous. In this case you can use `await`.

`var fileData = await getBase64(files[0]).catch(err=>{console.log(err});`

Comment: Please note that technically `await` doesn't perform synchronously - it only simplifies syntax.

Comment: `[rv] = await expression;`  expression: A Promise or any value to wait for. rv: Returns the fulfilled value of the promise, or the value itself if it's not a Promise

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: You can use `await` only in `async` functions, and it will pause execution until corresponding promise is resolved/rejected.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of `getBase64()` function `fileData` is not assigned *yet* because at that moment `.then` callback of promise has not been called.

The only place where it is set and defined is in callback of promise's `.then`. And as you stated, you do get data in `console.log(result)`.

You should familiarize yourself with asynchronous JS, here are some articles:

https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises